# Find Command not working - weird result inside a script when variable is passed to it ( challangeing one )

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

This code works find on it's own inside a batch file

```
 for /F "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /e /v "return code: 0" login.txt') do (
     echo %%i found a string that matched for example return code 1 login.txt
     goto :eof
  )
  :eof
```

Where the content of the login.txt is

```
   tstxtract return code: 0
   tstxtract return code: 0
   tstxtract return code:   1
```

So if there is any line that does not match the search criteria the echo command gets executed.. So far so good no problem ( thank you user zfus )

However I put the same code inside another script and this time I pass the file name as a variable from another function .. Something strange happens to the find command. first let me show you the script

```
 :extract
  dir /b /a-d | find /v "pstlist">pstlist
  FOR /F %%i in (pstlist) do (
  set pstname=%%i
  if exist c:\tokyo\scripts\output\%%i (
   mkdir C:\output\%%i_%todaydate%_%now%    
  echo **************** extraction result  >> c:\%extractlog%
  extract.exe -i -l c:\logs >> c:\%extractlog%   


 ) else (
    mkdir C:\output\%%i
     echo **************** extraction result  >> c:\%extractlog%
     extract.exe -i -l c:\logs >> c:\%extractlog%   
 ) 
 )
 goto chklog

 :chklog

     for /F "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /e /v "return code: 0" C:\%extractlog%') do (
          echo %%i found a string that matched for example return code 1 login.txt
           goto :eof
      )
     :eof

  :eof
   echo end & exit
```

Ok Please stay with me ..  Ok so as you see I'm now passing the C:\%extractlog% which is the location of the log file I want the findstr command to look into to the chklog function.

At this point the chklog function is the same code as the one I showed above with only difference that it is called by another function and a variable is passed on to it.

So what is the problem?

The findstr command now is not looking at the content of the file c:\%extractlog% but is looking at the %extractlog% file name. So if the %extraactlog% name is 12345.txt
 the findstr  command looks and find serach condition in the file name and not inside  it's content? So it is not even looking inside the file anymore. It's looking at the file-name ?  What am I doing wrong ? 
Can someone tell me>? Why is the findstr command is not looking at the contenet of the %extractlog% file?

Thanking you all in advance

Comment: maybe I should use /G ?

Comment: Do you have a file called %extractlog% under c:\ or do you have an environment variable called %extractlog%?

Comment: the file gets created when the extract function is called. The problem I'm seeing is that somehow the delims=" %%i or %%! in the :extract function gets passed on to :chklog function

Comment: that's why it's not working. But I have no idea how to reset the delims=" %%i ? Why it's picking the value from previous function?

Comment: What happens if you rename `%%i` in `:chklog` to `%%z` and also change `echo %%i` to `echo %%z`?

Comment: I tried that while ago - it  made no difference - I even placed the code in a nothe script and called the script from my script and that did not work either. The %%i value gets passed on .. there must be a way to reset it?

Comment: Add a new line after `:extract` and type `setlocal`. Add a line before goto chklog and type `endlocal`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Sorry I have to run out .. Thanks you  for all your help .. I will try this tomorrow and report back .. I hope this works though

Comment: Good day zfus .. I tried your suggesrion and places setlocal and endlocal in my script the result was the same. I have to figure out a way to serach for the content without use this without using DElime %%!. Any help will be welcomed

Comment: Do you have a file on c:\ named `%extract%`?

Answer (score 1):

`findstr` command use a /C switch to specify a string to search. It seems to me that the `C:\` of the filename is being taken as this option. I suggest you to enclose the filename in quotes this way:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /e /v "return code: 0" "C:\%extractlog%"') do (
```

Comment: ok - I used the quotes - the findstr works -when ther is a match I see this output ---------- C:\extract.TXT: 1 But when there is no match I get ---------- C:\extract.TXT: 0 ::: ( so u see o & 1 ) BUT in both occasions ( zero or One ) the do command executes the echo  command - it's not trapping what the findstr command chews out - .. Anyone please help? How do I trap the finstr  output zero and 1 .. I tried to trap errolevel and that does not work either